# What is $f(x)$ for which $\alpha (x)$ has been defined in this Lebesgue-Stieltjes integral?

Tags: lebesgue-integral

In a book I have found this example, where:

$$
\alpha (x) = \begin{cases}
0, & \mbox{if } x < 1, \\
x^2-2x+2, & \mbox{if } 1\le x < 2, \\
3, & \mbox{if } x = 2, \\
x+2, & \mbox{if } x > 2 
\end{cases}
$$
Then after some computation:
$$\int_{[0,3)}x^2 d\alpha = \dfrac{109}{6}$$

How $\alpha (x)$ is computed here and for what $f(x)$? Does $x^2$ mean some $f(x)^2$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function $f(x) = x^2$ is continuous.
Taking into account the jumps of $\alpha$, that occurs at $x=1$ and $x=2$, you get
$$
\int_{[1,3)} f(x) d\alpha(x) =
 f(1) [\alpha(1+) - \alpha(1-)] 
+\int_1^2 f(x) (2x-2) dx
+ f(2) [\alpha(2+) - \alpha(2-)] 
+ \int_2^3 f(x) dx 
$$
where, as usual, $\alpha(x\pm)$ denote the right and left limits of $\alpha$ at $x$.

Comment: Its like we're calculating second moment, $E[X^2]$, where $\alpha (x)$ is CDF, right?